# Entry page for a wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite

I am quite new too WP multisite, so forgive me for my ignorance on things.

I have set up multisite ok and have setup 4 sites (i am using subdomains)

> - mysite.com // the root site
> - london.mysite.com // subsite
> - oxford.mysite.com // subsite
> - manchester.london.com // subsite

All the subsites are using the same template, well child templates of the main template so i can change the background colour of the site for each particular subdomain.

on the `mysite.com` doamin, I would like to have a really simple page, could be static html for all i care, simply with links to each of the subdomains, there is to be no other content in this main domain just images or something similar so the visitor can go to the subsite they require.

Whats the best way of doing this? i take i i cant just upload a static `index.php` as this will break the subsites.

and as i have the default page for the site set to this i guess i have to load in the main wordpress index.php whatever i do.

thanks for your time and suguestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three options:

1. use a **Child Theme** on mysite.com, in which you replace index.php with whatever you want
2. Use a **different Theme entirely** on mysite.com - could be a landing-page Theme or whatever.
3. Use your current Theme on mysite.com, but set it to display a **static page as front page**, put your subsite links in the page content of the page displayed as the site front page, and remove all other content

Comment: thanks chip, thats nice to know i can use a child theme and completley replace the index.php page, with this method am i correct in thinking hat the menus etc in the original template will not be shown?

Comment: Whatever you replace in the Child Theme will be used, according to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). If your Parent Theme has a `front-page.php`, `home.php`, or `page.php` (that latter, if you use a static-page-as-front-page), you'll need to replace those files as well.